# Is it possible to access items in DataTemplate in the code?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Is it possible to access items in DataTemplate in the code? I mean, I have DataTemplate defined in Window.Resources like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" DataType="MyType">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Tag="ColorString">
            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="14" Margin="2,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Red">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=FillColor}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I need to set some properties of the Rectangle in the code. How can I do this? When DataTemplate is loaded its VisualTree is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Loaded event to the StackPanel and in code behind.

```
private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
    Rectangle rectangle = GetVisualChild<Rectangle>(stackPanel) as Rectangle;
    //..
}
```

This will not affect the DataTemplate itself but everytime it is used, StackPanel_Loaded will be called.

An implementation of GetVisualChild..

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject dependencyObject = parent as DependencyObject;
    return InternalGetVisualChild<T>(dependencyObject);
}
private static T InternalGetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```